# Is it normal for heißen to be used with objects?

Tags: word-usage

As the title says, is it normal to use the verb "heißen" to describe the names of objects/places as well, as opposed to merely people?

For example:

> Die Insel heißt "Malta"
>   Die Stadt heißt "Nürnberg"
>   Das Gemälde heißt "Mona Lisa"

If not, what word/phrasing should be used instead?

Comment: What makes you doubt about that, can you elaborate please? Of course that's _"normal"_.

Comment: I've simply never encountered this word used outside the context of people's names when studying and couldn't find an example when looking up texts. It wouldn't be strange to have different words for people and other objects. Like how you wouldn't say "Ich weiß ihn" but "Ich kenne ihn".

Comment: *Wissen* vs. *kennen* isn't about objects vs. people but about knowing a fact vs. being familiar with something or someone.

Comment: @Janka I understand the full nature of the distinction, but in particular it is an example where only one of two words would ever fit in the context of people, despite the fact that a direct translation from English might suggest otherwise.

Comment: @BarAlon: "Ich kenne dein Geheimnis" is perfect German.

Comment: You can also use the verb "nennen" in most cases, if you like. E.g. "Das Gemäde ist  'Mona Lisa' genannt"

Comment: @Beta Better _""Das Gemäde wird 'Mona Lisa' genannt""_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using *heißen* for objects is as normal as it is for people.

Answer (score 2):

Man kann die Frage ausweiten, ob es überhaupt Verben gibt, deren Gebrauch auf Personen beschränkt ist oder solche, die nicht für Personen benutzt werden können.

Mir fällt keins ein.

Semantisch mag es gelegentlich vorkommen.

Beim Essen unterscheidet man etwa gerne zwischen Menschen und Tieren - hier essen, da fressen. Aber bereits in einem Kinderbuch mit Familie Bär würde Mutter Bär die Kleinen wieder ohne Problem zum Essen rufen, wohl gerade um die strenge Unterscheidung zu unterlaufen.

Generell ist Menschsein keine wichtige Information, um einen korrekten Satz zu bilden.

Comment: Ich stimme voll und ganz zu. Ich hatte mal eine kontroverse Diskussion über das Wort _ärgerlich_. Es gelang mir allerdings nicht, die anderen davon zu überzeugen, dass Verursachender und Empfindender des Ärgers nicht davon abhängen können, ob das, was ärgerlich ist, belebt oder unbelebt ist ("die Sache / Felix ist ärgerlich").